# Excel Data Connection Updates Cell References Outside Table Range

Tags: excel, data-binding

Say I have set up a data connection in Excel to update columns `A-G` on a worksheet and sort on column A.  If I put a formula in the column `H` cells like `=SUM(B2:D2)`, then refresh the data connection, the column `H` cell references can get messed up.  For instance, the `H2` formula is now `=SUM(B7:D7)` instead of `=SUM(B2:D2)`.  I guessed the cause might be the data moving around in columns `A-G` due to my sort on column A.  But, changing the column `H`formula to use absolute row references - `=SUM(B$2:D$2)` - still results in references getting messed up.  It's as if Excel was moving entire rows of the spreadsheet rather than just the rows within the updated range.  So my questions are:

1) Has anybody else seen this behavior?

2) If you have seen this behavior, do you know how to turn it off?

Comment: What version of Excel? Is this an official Table (List in XL 2003)? If so, is column H within the list? If not, maybe it should be :).

Comment: It is Excel 2010 and I am using the Workbook Connections dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to extend the table to also cover column H! When you refresh your data, Excel differentiates between columns from the query and additional columns - and keeps the latter. At the same time, all columns get extended to whatever number of rows the query returns...

Comment: Thanks.  If I get a real lot of time, I may try that.  I finally gave up and canned the built-in wizardry for a home-grown mash-in of an ADO recordset.  Even this was more problematic than it should have been.  It should have been as simple as:

Comment: (1) variant = recordset.getrows(n) (2) range.value = variant.  Where range is a row in Excel.  But the array returned by getrows comes back - inexplicably - as array(cols, rows) rather than the directly usable (by Excel) form of array(rows, cols)...The variant array before using it to set the range value.  Even getting a single row results in an array(nCols, 0) which, as a two dimensional array with the second dimension as '1', is also not directly usable to set the range (if it's a row) and is just nuts in the bargain.

Comment: +1. The obvious solution that will save lots of time in the long run.